# What does the formula look like if I want a checkbox OR date fields to be true?

Tags: formula, date

Basically, once an opportunity is 100% closed/won (stage change), I'd like to have either of the following:

1. the checkbox copying Contract Start/End dates to Billable Start/End dates = true (if all dates are the same)

OR

2. Billable Start/End dates to be entered in manually (if contract and billing dates are diiferent) - checkbox can be unchecked

Comment: This looks like a workflow + validation rule. Where or what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom formula field.  When you create the field, you are asked what type of data to return, and this is where you specify ***CheckBox***.

Now, when writing your formula make sure it returns the same data type as you want for the return; for Checkbox, you will return a boolean (TRUE or FALSE).

Example Formula:

```
ISBLANK(Billable_End_Date__c)
```

If the billable end date is blank/null, this will return TRUE, else FALSE

Answer (score 0):

I might not fully understand the question but are you looking for a checkbox on an Opportunity that when it is checked the dates get copied over to another field and when it is unchecked then those fields stay blank [and then must be updated manually?].

Via a Workflow it would look like this

Workflow Rule on Opportunity
Trigger when created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria
Run this rule if the following formula evaluates to True

(Won = True && Checkbox__c = True && (Contract_Start__c <> Billable_Start__c || Contract_End__c <> Billable_End__c))

then have the field updates be

Object - Opportunity
Field to Update - Opportunity Billable_Start__c
Use a formula to set the new value

Billable_Start__c = Contract_Start__c

then another field update of

Object - Opportunity
Field to Update - Opportunity Billable_End__c
Use a Formula to set the new value

Billable_End__c = Contract_End__c

then attach those 2 updates to the workflow rule.

this can be done in a single Process in the process builder but because that isn't bulkified yet I'd stick to workflow rules.